# ES6 Class - map array of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, es6-class

Let's say that I have a list of 5 people's name

`let listNames = [Sam, Ash, Moe, Billy, Kenzi]`

and I want for each of the names to have properties of `doneHomeWork` and `lazy` using class

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.doneHomeWork = 0
        this.lazy = false
    }
}
```

instead of assigning each names as so :

```
const Sam = new Person()
const Ash = new Person()
const Moe = new Person()
const Billy = new Person()
const Kenzi = new Person()
```

I was thinking doing this

```
listNames.forEach(name => {
    name = new Person()
})
```

However, in my ESLint it's giving me  an error

> Assignment to function parameter 'name'  no-param-reassign

This seems trivial, but for some reason I am having trouble re-factoring this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the name variable is the one used for cycling inside the loop. 
You're changing this value in the first iteration of the loop. This is the reason of your error `Assignment to function parameter 'name' no-param-reassign`.

Then you are trying to use dynamic names as variables names. If you want to do it, the way is using bracket notation, so you could do it in this way:

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.doneHomeWork = 0
        this.lazy = false
    }
}
let persons = [];
let listNames = ['Sam', 'Ash', 'Moe', 'Billy', 'Kenzi'];

correctListNames.forEach(name => {
    persons[name] = new Person()
})

console.log(persons);
```

Comment: awesome! I just modified `let persons = {}` so I can avoid inserting an array, and `correctListNames` should be `listNames`. Other than that, thanks!

Comment: Sure objects can be accessed with the same notation. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 array destructuring and assign new instance of Person class to each name.

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.doneHomeWork = 0;
    this.lazy = false;
  }
}


const [Sam, Ash, Moe, Billy, Kenzi] = Array.from(Array(5), e => new Person)

console.log(Sam)
console.log(Ash)
```

Comment: Yeah but in this way you assume a finite number of persons. Otherwise this solution can't be dynamic and I t can't be applied. I think he was wondering how to iterate over an array of persons and create corresponding objects

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to dynamically generate this

```
const Sam = new Person();
const Randy = new Person():
```

You can get something similar by like this,

```
const persons = {
  Sam: new Person(),
  Randy: new Person(),
};
```

Then you can access them using `persons['Sam']` or `persons.Sam`.
Now to achieve this from an array,

```
const arr = ['Sam', 'Randy'];
const persons = {};
arr.forEach(name => {
  persons[name] = new Person();
});
```

> As for the eslint warning that you are getting is because you are trying to change the value of a parameter of a function. You can turn if off by setting the rule to 0 in your eslint configuration file. However I would recommend not to turn if off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 destructuring feature to achieve this:

```js
class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.doneHomeWork = 0
        this.lazy = false
    }
}
let arr = [];
for(let i=0;i<6;i++) {
 arr.push(new Person());
}


const [Sam, Ash, Moe, Billy, Kenzi] = [...arr];

console.log(Sam);
```